# How to combine 2 php functions into one function with a custom field

Tags: php, custom-field

I'm trying to get 2 php functions with my custom field to work together with a custom field. they both work by themselves great but I can't get them to work together.

The first function hides the last X characters of a custom field

```
<?php $custom_field = (string) get_post_meta( $post->ID, "XYZ", true ); echo substr( $custom_field, 0, -6 ); ?>
```

The second function removes the spaces of a custom field

```
<?php $custom_field = (string) get_post_meta( $post->ID, "XYZ", true ); echo str_replace(' ', '', $custom_field); ?>
```

My optimistically simple attempt at a solution was/is a disaster...

```
<?php $custom_field = (string) get_post_meta( $post->ID, "XYZ", true ); echo str_replace(' ', '', $custom_field); echo substr( $custom_field, 0, -6 ); ?>
```

Comment: Do not use `substr()`, use `mb_substr()` instead, or you will cut off multibyte characters in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

```
echo substr( $custom_field, 0, -6 );
echo str_replace(' ', '', $custom_field);
```

I think I solved it this way.

```
echo substr( str_replace(' ', '', $custom_field), 0, -6 );
```

Comment: this is what I used from your answer (and help from @toscho)... 

`<?php $custom_field = (string) get_post_meta( $post->ID, "XYZ", true ); echo mb_substr( str_replace(' ', '', $custom_field), 0, -3 ); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

[**@prosti**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/88606/prosti) is right, if you're looking for a function though, you can wrap both calls in a single reusable function.

```
function wpse250999_combine( $string ) {
    $output = substr( $string, 0, -6 );
    $output = str_replace(' ', '', $output );
    return $output;
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
$custom_field = wpse250999_combine( (string) get_post_meta( $post->ID, "XYZ", true ) );
echo $custom_field;
```

Comment: `@prosti is right` :) Usually I am not, but like what you said, thanks mate.